# Difference between "kind" and "kindly"

Tags: meaning, difference

> "Lead, **kindly** light, amid the encircling gloom,
>
> lead thou me on;
>
> the night is dark, and I am far from home;
>
> lead thou me on.
>
> Keep thou my feet; I do not ask to see
>
> the distant scene; one step enough for me......"
>
> From "Lead, Kindly Light" a hymn written in 1833 by John Henry Newman
>
> The hymn can be read here. 
>   https://www.godtube.com/popular-hymns/lead-kindly-light/

What is the difference between “kind” and “kindly” as adjectives?  Can I replace “kindly” (the part in bold) with “kind” here?

> Kind:
>
> : having or showing a gentle nature and a desire to help others
>   :wanting
>
> and liking to do good things and to bring happiness to others
>
> http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/kind#ld_entry_v2_jumplink_kind_2
>
> Kindly:
>
> [also more kindly; most kindly]
>
> : having or showing a gentle nature and a desire to help others :
>
> http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/kindly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used as adjectives, 'kind' and 'kindly' are synonyms. You may replace one with the other.

> Kindly
>   1. adjective [usually ADJECTIVE noun] A kindly person is kind, caring, and sympathetic. He was a stern critic but an extremely kindly man.
>   Synonyms: benevolent, kind, caring, nice

However, 'kindly' can be used as an adverb, meaning 'thoughtfully or helpfully'

[Kindly](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/kindly)

Comment: Is "kindly" archaic as an adjective?

Comment: Not archaic, no. Not even old-fashioned. Possibly used more often by educated people.